# Copy data against matching fields in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, slowdown

[image]
[image]
I am trying to copy data from the display sheet to relevant consumer # in bills sheet having (176000) rows, following code I found is working but it's very slow, around takes 5 minutes to execute one entry.

```
Sub SAVERECOVERY()

    For i = 5 To 125
        If Cells(i, 20) > 0 Then
           Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 20), 24) = Sheets("Display").Cells(i, 5)
           Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 20), 25) = Sheets("Display").Cells(i, 7)
           Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 20), 26) = Sheets("Display").Cells(i, 9)
           Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 20), 27) = Sheets("Display").Cells(i, 11)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Display sheet:
[image: Display]

Bills sheet:
[image: Bills]

Comment: For large amounts of data transfer use an array, build an array with all the data you need and then paste at once (this way you only work with excel 2 or 3 times instead 176k)

Comment: But you aren't adding data, you are changing it as I can see in the code, you are checking if a cell in column 20 is greater than 0, if so you are changing the same row from Bills as is in Display? That is your goal?

Comment: yes dear,that is exactly i wana do, i have around 175000 rows in bills, where data of bills of consumers is available, and now i have to change one segment of a consumer bill  for which i have developed a display sheet,

Comment: But let's assume one consumer has 3 separated rows of data. In your display sheet this consumer has also 3 rows of data, or just the one? Because if it's the later you are giving him only the last entry from bills sheet.

Comment: dear in display sheet only one consumer appears with month wise bills of same consumer from 2012 around 125 rows of data, so now i edit those bills in display sheet and i want the edited data to be saved in bills sheet against already existed data of same consumer.

Comment: Could you please upload an example(images) for a consumer in both sheets (without private data, just fictional or edited).

Comment: dear i have added pictures in main question,1st image is of display sheet and second is of bills.

Comment: Is it right to assume that the `Key` column on both sheets is the same? And it seems unique, so we can work with that to always change the data in Bills for the one in Display if their `Key` column match, right? If so, please tell me the column number for the `Key` column in both sheets and the column number for the data to be changed in both sheets.

Comment: So, you run the code with "Display" sheet being active. And the above code copies the values of columns 5, 7, 9, 11 (I see them being empty...) in  rows taken from Column 20, columns 24, 25, 26, 27 of "Bills" sheet. Is my understanding correct? If yes, are the rows in discussion (143252, 143253 etc.) at the end of the "Bills" worksheet, or not? Are the above mentioned row numbers consecutive? I also can see that the "Bills" worksheet is filtered. Are all the row numbers in discussion visible? Should it be filtered, or it happened to be so when you took the picture?

Comment: yes dear key column is same,so as rowid column, column "T" in display and column "W" in bills matches, yes as you said i will add new entries in display sheet column 5,7,9,11 and it will paste same in bills sheet after matching rowid.and yes bills worksheet is filterd, it contants record of 176000 consumers, each having uniquie row id, so when i change the consumer in display and add new enteries in ,5,7,9,11. it matches with row id in bills and paste new values in bills sheet column 24,25,26,27. my above code works perfect but takes around 5 minut to execute.

Comment: You missed answering to other some questions... I want understanding if it is possible to process everything in memory and drop the process data at once. Such an approach should take seconds. So, are all row numbers consecutive (on column 20 of "Display" sheet)? Is the area where to be pasted ("Bills" sheet) visible? Does it only happen that all columns value to be copied are empty? And, If you want me to see your comment, please tag me (@FaneDuru). Otherwise, I am not notified and I do not follow only your question...

Comment: yes dear all row numbers are consecutive, and area to be pasted is visble as well. and if it can be process in memory its not an issue,

Comment: Please test my answer code and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It should be very fast. It is only necessary to set the rows where the ranges will be copied (`firstRow`, `lastRow`) and take care to have the (consecutive) rows where the processing result to be pasted, in column 20. In fact, it would be enough to only write the first row:

```
Sub SAVERECOVERY()
 Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, shB As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet
 Dim arr24 As Variant, arr25 As Variant, arr26 As Variant, arr27 As Variant
 Dim pasteRow As Long, i As Long, arrRows As Variant
 
 Set shB = Sheets("Bills")
 Set shD = Sheets("Display")
 firstRow = 5: lastRow = 125: pasteRow = CLng(shD.cells(firstRow, 20))

 arr24 = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, 5), shD.cells(lastRow, 5)).value
 arr25 = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, 7), shD.cells(lastRow, 7)).value
 arr26 = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, 9), shD.cells(lastRow, 9)).value
 arr27 = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, 11), shD.cells(lastRow, 11)).value
 arrRows = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, 20), shD.cells(lastRow, 20)).value
 
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrRows)
    If arr24(i, 1) <> "" Then shB.cells(CLng(arrRows(i, 1)), 24).value = arr24(i, 1)
    If arr25(i, 1) <> "" Then shB.cells(CLng(arrRows(i, 1)), 25).value = arr25(i, 1)
    If arr26(i, 1) <> "" Then shB.cells(CLng(arrRows(i, 1)), 26).value = arr26(i, 1)
    If arr27(i, 1) <> "" Then shB.cells(CLng(arrRows(i, 1)), 27).value = arr27(i, 1)
  Next i
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  
 shB.Activate: shB.cells(pasteRow, 24).Select
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks dear, it works, but only issue is it should copy only data against filled cells, for instance if cells  in b4 to b134 in display sheet have empty cells it should not copy data from that rows column 5,7,9,11. but your code copies against values where it should not. i have attached new images please check and thanks in advance,in short as in your code last row should be the empty row in display sheet b5 to b130.

Comment: @rohail nisar: OK. No time now to look at the code. I will do it in about two hours... But, before that, you must clarify some aspects: If, we have to process 125 rows, like in your question, and only 5 such rows are not empty, will only these be pasted? I mean, the intermediary rows in "Bills" sheet do already contain data and must not be overwritten? Then, is it possible that in one column  (of 5, 7, 9, 11) the row to not be empty, but in the other columns to be empty? I mean, checking once for emptiness will be enough for all columns to be processed, or not?

Comment: @rohail nisar: Try the updated code, please. It will check every column for empty cells and copy only the non empty ones. Please, send some feedback, too. I did not check it, but it should work. I must leave the office for a while. If it will work as you need, we here vote the answer code up and more important, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works...